# Privatizing a GitHub repo makes the stars fade away?

Tags: github, repository, private

For a paper, we had to publish my code. Now the professor asked students to implement it also, and he asked me to "make the repo invisible for a month".

The only way I think I can do that is by paying for a month and get it private.

The question: Are its stars (26 in that [project](https://github.com/gsamaras/Dolphinn)) going to be lost? In other words, when I make it public again in one month, are the stars going to be 26 or 0?

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is, though I suspect your stars will come back. Why not test with a dummy repo? In any case, what's the motivation to "make the repo invisible for a month"? There may be a better way to achieve whatever that goal is.

Comment: @Chris a dummy repo requires me to pay. I haven't set any repos as private before. The goal of the prof is that the students won't be able to find the code online.

Comment: GitHub offers a [student pack](https://education.github.com/pack) that provides "unlimited private repositories (normally $7/month) while you are a student". It sounds like you might qualify: "If you're a student aged 13+ and enrolled in a degree or diploma granting course of study, the GitHub Student Developer Pack is for you. All you need is a school-issued email address, valid student identification card, or other official proof of enrollment." Several other services are included as well.

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris, I wasn't aware of the offer. I applied for it, when I have news, I will let you know.

Comment: @Chris our guesses were wrong. You lose all the stars and watchers. I was thinking of deleting the question, but since our feeling was wrong, I am wondering if other people might have that wrong impression, so I posted an answer instead. What do you think?

Comment: Works for me. Thanks for doing the legwork and providing an answer for other users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You permanently lose all your stars and watchers, as the picture mentions:

[image]